# Map conditional types back to a union type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, conditional-types

I am trying to do the following (also [see it on TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RequestType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'baz'%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SomeRequest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20RequestType%0D%0A%20%20sessionId%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20params%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResult%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20sendWorkRequest%3CT%20extends%20RequestType%3E(%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20...params%0D%0A)%3A%20Promise%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'baz'%20%3F%20boolean%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20await%20this.readyDeferred.promise%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20request%3A%20SomeRequest%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bucket%3A%20'bucket'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionId%3A%20'some%20session%20id'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%5B1%2C'two'%2C3%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20const%20p%20%3D%20new%20Promise%3CResponseResult%3E(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20this.requests%5Brequest.id%5D%20%3D%20p%0D%0A%20%20this.worker.postMessage(request)%0D%0A%20%20return%20p%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)), but I get an error on the return type of the function that tells me the conditional type can not be assigned to the union:

```
type RequestType =
  | 'foo'
  | 'bar'
  | 'baz'

interface SomeRequest {
  id: string
  type: RequestType
  sessionId: string
  bucket: string
  params: Array<any>
}

type ResponseResult = string | number | boolean

async function sendWorkRequest<T extends RequestType>(
    type: T,
    ...params
  ): Promise<
    T extends 'foo'
      ? string
      : T extends 'bar'
        ? number
        : T extends 'baz' ? boolean : never
  > {
    await this.readyDeferred.promise

    const request: SomeRequest = {
      id: 'abc',
      bucket: 'bucket',
      type,
      sessionId: 'some session id',
      params: [1,'two',3],
    }
    const p = new Promise<ResponseResult>((/*...*/) => {/*...*/})

    this.requests[request.id] = p
    this.worker.postMessage(request)
    return p // <-------------------------------- ERROR
  }
```

Basically, I want the conditional type to result in one of the types of the `ResponseResult` type. So based on the `type` argument passed into the function, it should return one of the types in the `ResponseResult` union (as a Promise).

How can I make this work, so that the type of the `type` argument determines the type of Promise returned?

---

Here's [another way](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RequestType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'baz'%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SomeRequest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20RequestType%0D%0A%20%20sessionId%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20params%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResult%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20sendWorkRequest%3CT%20extends%20ResponseResult%20%3D%20never%3E(%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20RequestType%2C%0D%0A%20%20...params%0D%0A)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20await%20this.readyDeferred.promise%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20request%3A%20SomeRequest%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bucket%3A%20'bucket'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionId%3A%20'some%20session%20id'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%5B1%2C'two'%2C3%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20const%20p%20%3D%20new%20Promise%3CT%3E(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20this.requests%5Brequest.id%5D%20%3D%20p%0D%0A%20%20this.worker.postMessage(request)%0D%0A%20%20return%20p%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20DOESN'T%20WORK%0D%0Aasync%20function%20test1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20await%20sendWorkRequest('foo')%0D%0A%20%20result.split('')%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atest1()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20WORKS%0D%0Aasync%20function%20test2()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20await%20sendWorkRequest%3Cstring%3E('foo')%0D%0A%20%20result.split('')%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atest2()) to do it without conditional types, but I want to know if it can be done using the conditional type for the `type` arg.

---

EDIT: Based on Erik's answer below, I am also curious why [this one](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RequestType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'baz'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SomeRequest%3CTType%20extends%20RequestType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20TType%3B%0D%0A%20%20sessionId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20params%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResult%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResultOptions%3CT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20'foo'%20%3F%20string%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'bar'%20%3F%20number%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'baz'%20%3F%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20sendWorkRequest%3CT%20extends%20RequestType%3E(%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20...params%0D%0A)%3A%20Promise%3CResponseResult%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20await%20this.readyDeferred.promise%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20request%3A%20SomeRequest%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bucket%3A%20'bucket'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionId%3A%20'some%20session%20id'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%5B1%2C%20'two'%2C%203%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20p%20%3D%20new%20Promise%3CResponseResultOptions%3CT%3E%3E(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20this.requests%5Brequest.id%5D%20%3D%20p%3B%0D%0A%20%20this.worker.postMessage(request)%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20p%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20await%20sendWorkRequest('foo')%0D%0A%20%20result.split('string')%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atest()) won't work, and if it is possible to make it work without redefining `ResponseResult` and without changing the return type of the function.

@Erik, [second example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RequestType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'baz'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SomeRequest%3CTType%20extends%20RequestType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20TType%3B%0D%0A%20%20sessionId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20params%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResult%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResultOptions%3CT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20'foo'%20%3F%20string%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'bar'%20%3F%20number%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'baz'%20%3F%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20sendWorkRequest%3CT%20extends%20RequestType%3E(%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20...params%0D%0A)%3A%20Promise%3CResponseResult%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20await%20this.readyDeferred.promise%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20request%3A%20SomeRequest%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bucket%3A%20'bucket'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionId%3A%20'some%20session%20id'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%5B1%2C%20'two'%2C%203%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20p%20%3D%20new%20Promise%3CResponseResultOptions%3CT%3E%3E(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20this.requests%5Brequest.id%5D%20%3D%20p%3B%0D%0A%20%20this.worker.postMessage(request)%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20p%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20await%20sendWorkRequest('foo')%20as%20string%0D%0A%20%20result.split('string')%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atest()).

Comment: Once you declared your `SomeRequest.RequestType` you can never know the actual type at compile time.  Why not `SomeRequest<TType extends RequestType>` with `type: TType` as the property?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Doesn't matter, this is just about the types. In reality it will be resolved.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Not entirely sure what you mean. Mind editing my playground example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encapsulate the Type as (*assumption*) typescript can't assume (calculate) two non-referenced conditional types are the same.

So instead do

```
type ResponseResult<T> =
  T extends 'foo'
    ? string
    : T extends 'bar'
      ? number
      : T extends 'baz' ? boolean : never;
```

Now you can change the signature of the function to:

```
async function sendWorkRequest<T extends RequestType>(
  type: T,
  ...params
  ): Promise<ResponseResult<T>> {
```

and update `p`:

```
const p = new Promise<ResponseResult<T>>(() => { });
```

[TypeScript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RequestType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'baz'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SomeRequest%3CTType%20extends%20RequestType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20TType%3B%0D%0A%20%20sessionId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20params%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResult%3CT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20string%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20number%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'baz'%20%3F%20boolean%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20sendWorkRequest%3CT%20extends%20RequestType%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20...params%0D%0A%20%20)%3A%20Promise%3CResponseResult%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20await%20this.readyDeferred.promise%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20request%3A%20SomeRequest%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bucket%3A%20'bucket'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionId%3A%20'some%20session%20id'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%5B1%2C%20'two'%2C%203%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20p%20%3D%20new%20Promise%3CResponseResult%3CT%3E%3E(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20this.requests%5Brequest.id%5D%20%3D%20p%3B%0D%0A%20%20this.worker.postMessage(request)%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20p%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

> Do you know why or how to do it without changing the return type and without modifying the definition of the return type?

No because a `Conditional Type` not equal to a `Type`.

> Does that one require an explicit type cast in the place where the function is called?

No, I can mock the promise with a property of type and see the it is of that type:

[TypeScript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20RequestType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20'baz'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SomeRequest%3CTType%20extends%20RequestType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20TType%3B%0D%0A%20%20sessionId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20bucket%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20params%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResponseResult%3CT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20'foo'%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20string%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20number%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%20extends%20'baz'%20%3F%20boolean%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20function%20sendWorkRequest%3CT%20extends%20RequestType%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20...params%0D%0A%20%20)%3A%20PromiseMock%3CResponseResult%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20request%3A%20SomeRequest%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bucket%3A%20'bucket'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sessionId%3A%20'some%20session%20id'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%5B1%2C%20'two'%2C%203%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20p%20%3D%20new%20PromiseMock%3CResponseResult%3CT%3E%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20p%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PromiseMock%3CResponseResult%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20prop%3A%20ResponseResult%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20promiseMockFoo%20%3D%20sendWorkRequest('foo')%3B%0D%0A%2F%2Fprop%20is%20a%20string%2C%20you%20can%20hover%20the%20value%20in%20the%20playground%20to%20see%20the%20value%0D%0Aconsole.log(promiseMockFoo.prop)%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20promiseMockBar%20%3D%20sendWorkRequest('bar')%3B%0D%0A%2F%2Fprop%20is%20a%20number%2C%20you%20can%20hover%20the%20value%20in%20the%20playground%20to%20see%20the%20value%0D%0Aconsole.log(promiseMockBar.prop)%20%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20promiseMockBaz%20%3D%20sendWorkRequest('baz')%3B%0D%0A%2F%2Fprop%20is%20a%20booelean%2C%20you%20can%20hover%20the%20value%20in%20the%20playground%20to%20see%20the%20value%0D%0Aconsole.log(promiseMockBaz.prop)%20)

> Is there a way to make it safe (no type cast)?

Not necessary

Comment: Super duper awesoooome!! Thanks! In the example playground I appended to my question (based on the one in your answer here), the return value is not inferred to be a string. Do you know why or how to do it without changing the return type and without modifying the definition of the return type? Does that one require an explicit type cast in the place where the function is called? Is there a way to make it safe (no type cast)?

Comment: I meant, for example goo.gl/DKAg9B, See where I cast with `as string`. Is it possible to do that without a cast, and *without* modifying the `Promise<ResponseResult>` return type, and without modifying the definition of `ResponseResult` in that example?

Comment: Yes, **stop changing** the result type to `: Promise<ResponseResult>`, and use the correct result type `: Promise<ResponseResultOptions<T>>`.

Comment: I get it. I was just curious if it was possible to leave the return type as `Promise<ResponseResult>`, so I suppose you mean "no". :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively in order to get type inference working you can provide override declarations:

```
type ResponseResult = string | number | boolean

async function sendWorkRequest(type: 'foo', ...params): Promise<string>
async function sendWorkRequest(type: 'bar', ...params): Promise<number>
async function sendWorkRequest(type: 'baz', ...params): Promise<boolean>
async function sendWorkRequest(type: RequestType, ...params): Promise<ResponseResult> {
  /* ... */
  const p = new Promise<ResponseResult>((/* ... */) => {/* ... */})
  /* ... */
}

// WORKS
async function test1() {
  const result = await sendWorkRequest('foo')
  result.split('')
}

test1()
```